# Clear browser cache and history with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use Selenium WebDriver 3.141.59 with ChromeDriver and try to remove browser cache and history during test execution.
I have found several solutions about using `chrome://settings/clearBrowserData` page in test scripts, but these seems flaky.

In v4.0, there will be a better solution to interact with DevTools, but it isn't yet released.

```
driver.getDevTools().createSessionIfThereIsNotOne();
driver.getDevTools().send(Network.clearBrowserCookies());
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever chrome opens it stores info in a profile folder. The best solution might be to create a custom profile folder every time you start the driver.

```
ChromeOptions chromeProfile = new ChromeOptions();
chromeProfile.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeProfile);
```